# How to run Plasma (KDE) session in Xubuntu 16.04.5 running xfce by default?

Tags: xubuntu, session, kde-plasma-5

When I logout on Xubuntu (xfce) I get a screen to login again, on top bar of this screen is placed an icon and when click it the drop down menu offers 3 options to login: Plasma, xfce and Xubuntu. By default the login is set to Xubuntu, but now I tried Plasma then I get KDE desktop screen and it stuck, displaying a error message that some packages/libraries are missing. I was able to open task manager and ended some processes to return to Xubuntu session. How to fix this issue? do I need to install some pcks to fix that? Another question : what the difference btw xfce and Xubuntu session? thnaks, vladi.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use KDE if it has been installed properly. You can use the command

```
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
```

to install all of the packages that Kubuntu needs for its KDE version. Then it should work.

However, I would recommend that you upgrade to 18.04.1 LTS before you do this, as KDE got many improvements in the past few years, including bug fixes and performance increases. If all you want is KDE, you could do a clean install of Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

For the differences between XFCE and Xubuntu session, see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/296597/what-is-the-differences-between-xfce-session-and-xubuntu-session